# Detecting if onscroll events working / supported in browser

Tags: javascript, scroll, onscroll

Is there a way to find out if javascript onscroll event is supported in a browser?
Because i am working on a WebApp for android and iphones, and the onscroll event is working for android but not for iphone.
So is there any way in javascript by which i can detect if its supported in that browser?

Comment: onscroll should just work in the newer versions of iOS. What version are you testing on?

Comment: Checking for event support: `typeof window.onscroll!=="undefined"` or `Object.getPrototypeOf(window).hasOwnProperty("onscroll")`

Comment: also facing this issue on blackberry 5.

Comment: @Andrew put that as an answer so that i can accept!  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking for event support:

```
typeof window.onscroll!=="undefined";
```

or

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(window).hasOwnProperty("onscroll");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try those older answers, basicly, its a problem specific to Safari on iPhone:

[onscroll event not being triggered on iPad after single touch panning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216766/onscroll-event-not-being-triggered-on-ipad-after-single-touch-panning)

[javascript scroll event for iPhone/iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863547/javascript-scroll-event-for-iphone-ipad)

Comment: also facing this issue on blackberry 5.